# Workaround for FacialRecognizer class for OpenCV 3.1

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to recognize faces using the eigenfaces algorithm with opencv 3.1 and python. I have come across that the FaceRecognizer class is no longer included in 3.1. So is there any workarounds to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [facereclib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/facereclib) package that is a Python facial recognizer for Python 3.x:

> Compare a variety of face recognition algorithms by running them on
>   many image databases with default protocols. This library is designed to perform a fair comparison of face recognition algorithms. It contains scripts to execute various kinds of face recognition experiments on a variety of facial image databases.

[Facereclib documentaion](http://pythonhosted.org/facereclib/)

And for install easy use `pip`:

`pip install facereclib`

Answer (score 0):

The Face Recognizer stuff was moved to opencv_contrib 
You need to build opencv_contrib in order to access cv2.face

after you build if u get this response then you have correctly installed the sub module face

```
    help(cv2.face)
    Help on module cv2.face in cv2:

    NAME
        cv2.face

    FILE
        (built-in)

    FUNCTIONS
        MinDistancePredictCollector(...)
            MinDistancePredictCollector([, threshhold]) -> <face_MinDistancePredictCollector object>

        MinDistancePredictCollector_create(...)
            MinDistancePredictCollector_create([, threshold]) -> retval

        createEigenFaceRecognizer(...)
            createEigenFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval

        createFisherFaceRecognizer(...)
            createFisherFaceRecognizer([, num_components[, threshold]]) -> retval

        createLBPHFaceRecognizer(...)
            createLBPHFaceRecognizer([, radius[, neighbors[, grid_x[, grid_y[, threshold]]]]]) -> retval
```

[Here](http://hanzratech.in/2015/02/03/face-recognition-using-opencv.html) is a very nice tutorial for using cv2.face in opencv3.1 python

Comment: I don't get the first the two functions. Is there any way by which I can add them ?

Comment: Whats your opencv version?

Comment: it said 3.1.0-dev, but I've uninstalled it and now I'm going to build it again